# Displaying Content to certain user agent - Content displays small on mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Here's my code: **http://jsfiddle.net/1s1owxwk/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                $('#container.mobile').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#container.desktop').fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
```

Essentially all I'm doing is displaying mobile content for mobile and desktop version for desktop.

For some strange reason when I try and view this online, the content appears smaller?  Does anybody have any ideas as to why this would be?

**Full Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CODE</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                $('#container.mobile').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#container.desktop').fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #container.desktop {width: 960px; height: 300px; background: #e3e3e3; display: none; margin: 0 auto;}
        #container.mobile {width: 300px; height: 300px; background: #333; display: none; margin: 0 auto;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>


<div id="container" class="desktop"></div>
<div id="container" class="mobile"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing on mobile devices - The "mobile" grey box SHOULD fill the mobile screen but doesn't.  It scales it down - My container is still 300px wide, but the body around it 964px.  No idea how that's happened?

[image]

I've also tried media queries.  This works when resizing on desktop, but mobiles still load in the desktop content regardless?

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px) {
        #container.desktop {display: none;}
    }       

    @media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 6000px) {
        #container.mobile {display: none;}
    }
```

Any help would be great because I'm well and truly lost!

Comment: have you tried using the [viewport meta tag?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) - specifically `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Thank you @lemieuxster!  If you want to answer the question it's yours! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)! - specifically

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```